# Ownership of group in Active Directory,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

Web application MVC3 C#.

I am using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to manage Active Directory.

Does anybody know the way I can see a group owner? `managedBy` property?

I am finding the group

```
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(directory, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName);
```

but I do not see the way to look for ownership of the group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If that property you need isn't available on the `GroupPrincipal`, the new `S.DS.AM` approach has a pretty good extensibility story.

[Read more about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S10) - you can basically extend `GroupPrincipal` and in that extended class, you can "reach down" into the underlying `DirectoryEntry` and fetch additional properties that didn't make it into the `GroupPrincipal`.

Also [check out this CodeProject article](How to use AD Attributes not represented in UserPrincipal, GroupPrincipal and ComputerPrincipal) on how to extend `S.DS.AM` (shown with `UserPrincipal` but works just the same for `GroupPrincipal`)

Comment: Indeed, there is an underlying object in GroupPrincipal.

Quick and dirty  solution would be,

var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(directory, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName));
DirectoryEntry obj =(DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject();
var owner = obj.Properties["managedBy"];

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there is an underlying object in `GroupPrincipal`.

Quick and dirty solution would be:

```
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(directory, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName));
DirectoryEntry obj =(DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject();
var owner = obj.Properties["managedBy"];
```

Thank you very much!